# Visual Basic going through each row and writing the value of first column of each row in different labels

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I have managed to write the value of the first row in label1, but I do not know why I cannot get the value of second row in label2. Here is how far I've managed to come

```
    myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT allText FROM tbltest"
    myDatareader = myCommand.ExecuteReader

    Do While myDatareader.Read()
        label1.Text = myDatareader(0).ToString()
        label2.Text = myDatareader(1).ToString()
    Loop
```

PS! i get this error "index was outside the bounds of the array". What is it that I'm doing wrong?

PSS! With help from Alex, I wrote these and it fixed the problem. 
What it does is, it reads the values and writes them as labels inside a Panel.

**solution**

```
    Public Sub getit()
        Dim count As Integer = 0

        myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT allText FROM tbltest"
        myDatareader = myCommand.ExecuteReader

        Do While myDatareader.Read
            count += 1
            show(myDatareader(0).ToString, count)
        Loop
    End Sub

    Public Sub show(ByVal name As String, ByVal count As Integer)
        Dim allTextlabel As New Label()

        allTextlabel.Location = New Point(10, (45 * (count)) + 1)
        allTextlabel.Size = New Size(100, 25)
        allTextlabel.Name = "lbl_" & name.ToString
        allTextlabel.Text = name.ToString

        Panel1.Controls.Add(allTextlabel)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you requested just one column `myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT allText FROM tbltest"` which is `allText` you haven't any `myDatareader(1)` just first one which index is 0 `myDatareader(0)`

**UPDATE** I am not very strong in VB but you can try:

```
Dim Phrase() as string
i=0

Do While myDatareader.Read()
    i=i+1
    Phrase(i) = myDatareader(0).ToString();
Loop

    label1.Text = Phrase(1).ToString()
    label2.Text = Phrase(2).ToString()
    label3.Text = Phrase(3).ToString()
    label4.Text = Phrase(4).ToString()
    label5.Text = Phrase(5).ToString()
```

Comment: Thank you, i see the problem now. Do you have any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: That is up to you. You can query more columns, or you can comment `label2..=` line

Comment: But i don't want to add more columns, i wanna add the value of second row into label2. if that makes any sense :)

Comment: how many labels do you have? are you sure that you can set so many labels?

Comment: ive got five rows and five labels. im not sure if i should use Datareader or just put everything in a DataTable, but then i dont know how to pull them out one by one

Comment: Thank you, it helped me understand the problem and find a solution. I'm gonna update my post to show you what i did.